# Prove or disprove the existence of: (1) An equilateral triangle on $\mathbb Z^2$ (2) A regular hexagon on $\mathbb Z^3$ (3) A regular nonagon on $Z^4$

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

My attempt

$$ A = (0, 0) , B = (1, 0) , C = \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) $$

The distance between $A$ and $B$ is 1, and the distance between $A$ and $C$ is also 1. Therefore, the points $A, B$, and $C$ form an equilateral triangle in $\mathbb Z^2$.

In $\mathbb Z^3$, a regular hexagon would consist of six equilateral triangles meeting at a common center point. To have all integer coordinates, we need to use points that have integer values. Unfortunately, it is not possible to find a regular hexagon with all integer coordinates in $\mathbb Z^3$ because the distances between the vertices of a regular hexagon involve square roots of 3 or other irrational numbers, which do not result in integers.

In $\mathbb Z^4$, a regular nonagon would consist of nine equilateral triangles meeting at a common center point. Again, to have all integer coordinates, we need to use points with integer values.

Comment: $C$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Comment: Do we allow skew polygons like the pentagon(s) with 60° angles formed when we cycle through the vertices of a 4-simplex? It does not affect the yes/no answers for these specific cases, but it impacts the method of proof.